# Typescript generic type does not enforce type safety

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to generate a generic function that allow me to generate a strongly typed setter for a given type, with a callback - e.g:

```js
interface Foo {
   a: number,
   b: string
}

magick('a', 43) => {} // Should work
magick('a', '43') => {} // Should fail
```

I've implemented a generic function that does this - and it works. But however if I try to copy that function type safety is not enforced (or more likely I'm misunderstanding typescript!)

```js
interface Test {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface Test2 {
  a2: boolean;
  b2: '+' | '-';
}

const testVal: Test = {
  a: 42,
  b: 'test',
};

type Demo<T> = <K extends keyof T> (key: K, val: T[K]) => void

const implDemo: Demo<Test> = (key, val) => {
  testVal[key] = val;
};
```

Firstly - the function is working as how I want it:

```js
/* prints: {a: 10, b: "test"} - correct  */
implDemo('a', 10); console.log(testVal); 

/* Fails as expected - type safety - a should be number */
implDemo('a', 'text');
```

But why is this following possible? How Can `Demo<Test2>`
 be assignable to `Demo<Test>`

```js
/* Create a pointer to implDemo - but with WRONG type!!! */
const implDemo2: Demo<Test2> = implDemo; 
implDemo2('a2', true); 
console.log(testVal); 
/* prints: {a: 10, b: "test", a2: true} - we just violated out type!!!! */
```

What we just did above is the same as doing:

```js
testVal['a2'] = true; /* Doesn't work - which it shouldn't! */
```

Here is another simply type, where type safety is actually enforced

```js
type Demo2<T> = (val: T) => void;
const another: Demo2<string> = (val) => {};
/* This fails - as expected */
const another2: Demo2<number> = another;
```

Is this a bug in typescript - or am I misunderstanding something? My suspicion is that type `Demo<T> = <K extends keyof T>` is the culprit, but I simply don't understand how I'm allowed to "hack" the typesystem this way.

Comment: Yeah this looks like a compiler bug to me; not sure if it's been reported already.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say this is a compiler bug.  <strike>I'm not sure if it has been [reported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) yet; so far I haven't found anything by searching, but that doesn't mean it isn't there.</strike>  EDIT: I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31006) about this behavior; we'll see what happens.  UPDATE: looks like this might be [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31029) for <strike>TS3.5</strike> <strike>TS3.6</strike> <strike>TS3.7</strike>... who knows !

Here's a reproduction:

```
interface A { a: number; }
interface B { b: string; }

type Demo<T> = <K extends keyof T> (key: K, val: T[K]) => void

// Demo<A> should not be assignable to Demo<B>, but it is?!
declare const implDemoA: Demo<A>;
const implDemoB: Demo<B> = implDemoA; // no error!? 

// Note that we can manually make a concrete type DemoA and DemoB:
type DemoA = <K extends keyof A>(key: K, val: A[K]) => void;
type DemoB = <K extends keyof B>(key: K, val: B[K]) => void;

type MutuallyAssignable<T extends U, U extends V, V=T> = true;
// the compiler agrees that DemoA and Demo<A> are mutually assignable
declare const testAWitness: MutuallyAssignable<Demo<A>, DemoA>; // okay
// the compiler agrees that DemoB and Demo<B> are mutually assignable
declare const testBWitness: MutuallyAssignable<Demo<B>, DemoB>; // okay

// And the compiler *correctly* sees that DemoA is not assignable to DemoB
declare const implDemoAConcrete: DemoA;
const implDemoBConcrete: DemoB = implDemoAConcrete; // error as expected
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type 'DemoA' is not assignable to type 'DemoB'.
```

[Link to code‍](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmSAVwFsAjaAbmQF8AoUSWRFAIU2RLwGcwpQBzSrRpgAngAcUAEQhEA9gB4AKgD5kAXmTyA0sggAPSCAAmnZAGsII2TGQrkACgsi8WgDTIAbnAA2eRQG0tAF0ASnVVD1lgIxoaAHo45Gk5eVRVTgALWQJvI3xZMHYUOE5OYD4QOBJvFDBZJJkFZmV3EgJC4A7OAH4AQhojCARvOCgUBFkQbmRgIjFvZNlUPEXU5XIaCamOuYXG5hXG+Wb1Gd3F1EoE-N0oKFkoXu7kQF4NwFQ92OuAOQLajLhCgB3cZwEDIIiggg+bwicFwCzYZBbBBjSDIUQSBpydCgvKLA7CcRSRroDTaXQGCDGUxOaxoZSOSwudxeXxoQKhcKeKJGDYY4lyVhknT6QwmcyWOnNRnOZBuTw+PDMDlhNQRHkbQmYgCy7Sh3hhqFK5Uq1QgSgpYtMAFV3NbLVTxQA1dxOtR2DQ8AgQDbXMAZcayObAGpQbB8MYQUz+gFYpbYYxxtbYMbgvXQ2ElMoVKo1AZDEaprbTSDcVAAdU6ICjnDwurA+sNxpzZvkqzS7gu62Q11kZjgIniiX9geDofDkej-0K+ITeKOJ1GKCI6YNmebprzg2GS6RkxLUbAzErYGrpTrq6b2c35tWzU7+27vf7g6HaETI73Y+gyAAVBM7iGMAYV-ZBOAgKN0WnON0GAUwQAKbAN1zWp6nxfMdyLfcdnmC4AGFJhRCBIEObENmLHC9kFAiQCIki4yFM5cJJGi6J9HtEmge4wxKCkJAQSAYmuZARIAP3EiTJKk8TNAAWlk2wiWQAByC5lJmeDEKzE0UPRep+RU-FlIAOiAA)

You can see that `DemoA` and `Demo<A>` are basically the same type (they are mutually assignable, meaning a value of one type can be assigned to a variable of the other).  And `DemoB` and `Demo<B>` are also the same type.  And the compiler does understand that `DemoA` is not assignable to `DemoB`.

But the compiler thinks that `Demo<A>` is assignable to `Demo<B>`, which is your problem.  It's as if the compiler "forgets" what `T` in `Demo<T>` is.

---

If you really need to work around this for now you might want to brand `Demo<T>` with something that will "remember" what `T` is, but doesn't stop you from assigning your implementation to it:

```
// workaround    
type Demo<T> = (<K extends keyof T> (key: K, val: T[K]) => void) & {__brand?: T};

const implDemoA: Demo<A> = (key, val) => {} // no error
const implDemoB: Demo<B> = implDemoA; // error here as expected
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Yes I was toying around with it and found a similar solution - it really seems like it forgets T:`type Demo<T> = <K extends keyof T> (key: K, val: T[K], hack?: T) => void` - but your solution is better!

Comment: Well I searched and searched through the GitHub issues but I can't find anything. I might file an issue about it unless you want to do it.

Comment: Ill keep the question open for a another day, maybe the hivemind has an answer :) Maybe wait a day, and if no-one else has an idea you file an issue? Thx for the feedback!

Comment: I've filed [Microsoft/TypeScript#31006](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31006).

Comment: And there's already a tentative [fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31029) for it, possibly slated for TypeScript 3.5.

Comment: Looks like the fix has been pushed back to TS3.6

Comment: This fix keeps getting pushed back; it hasn't been added to "the backlog" yet, but it has been delayed every release, so ‍♂️